# Add two prices to make one

Tags: linq-to-sql

Morning,

I would like to know how i could add two prices from my database to make one price. My current code is below.

```
 orderPriceTotal = oi.price + oi.shippingPrice,
```

All help is much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Without the context we can't help.

Comment: this would just show the price and the shipping price. I need to add them both together to make one price :)

Comment: are these strings rather than numerical values then?

Comment: In that case it should just work. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.. but i think if these aren't in numerical values then first u need to convert into numerical then do addition.

Answer (score 0):

If `oi.price` and `oi.shippingPrice` are numeric (hopefully `decimal`) values then what you have should just work.

If they are already strings then go back to the data source and return them as decimal values.

If you can't do that then you'll need to convert them back to numerical values, add them and then convert back into a string.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = <your culture>;
decimal price;
if (decimal.TryParse(oi.price, NumberStyles.Currency, culture, out price);
```

The `NumberStyles.Currency` will allow you to parse a string that might contain a currency symbol.

Do the same for `shippingPrice` then:

```
orderPriceTotal = (price + shippingPrice).ToString("C", culture);
```

to convert back to a string complete with the correct currency symbol.